# jquery accordion collapse and css issue

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

I have an accordion with a custom stylesheet from themeroller. the problem is that when I collapse one of the parts of the accordion it changes the collapsed header to black instead of going back to the original red color. I have looked through css and my only thought is this a is a javascript issue bc my hover color is black and for some reason it is staying that color when collapsed.

here is a link http://filtersavvy.com/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=351_448&sort=20a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for this CSS rule

```
.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
    background: url("/includes/templates/theme376/css/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_100909_1x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #F50019;
    border: 1px solid #F50019;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

The issue is caused by the class `.ui-state-focus` which displays the black background for the clicked menu item while it has focus. Remove the class from that rule or redefine it like this:

```
.ui-state-focus { background: none }
```

Comment: worked the only thing I would add is to only remove the first instance of .ui-state-focus in the rule

Comment: yeap, I mentioned that - "_Remove the class from that rule_" :)

Answer (score 0):

When you click to close a header, `<h3>` gains the class `ui-state-focus`.  You could check to see if the click is closing it and if so, Remove the class `ui-state-focus`, which would change the css rule that is being applied.